# How to open my port / what is blocking my port?

Tags: ubuntu

i have remote access to ubuntu server with public domain/ip there is running apache on port 80 and i can see that, running jboss4 on 8080 also opened,

the thing is i installed mysql, glassfish both are running cause i can use them on localhost (with phpmyadmin, mysql...) but they are not accesible from outside

netstat:

```
glasshish  
tcp6       0      0 :::14848                :::*                    LISTEN      6590/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::18080                :::*                    LISTEN      6590/java       
tcp6       0      0 :::18181                :::*                    LISTEN      6590/java 

apache 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      15862/java        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      613/apache2    

mysql 
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      17274/mysqld
```

what else should i check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for MySQL try the following

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Enter your password and verify that you can connect (ok I know it is shown in netstat fair enough, you should be able to connect)

If you haven't already added a user for remote access do so:

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'monty'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'some_pass';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'monty'@'%'
->     WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The above will create a user for access from ALL hosts - NOT ADVICED. Replace % with the IP address you want to connect from.

Lastly make sure you have set a bind address in /etc/my.cnf like so:

```
bind-address=YOURIP
```

If you have done all of the above some firewall rule is blocking you or you have some strange routing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Few ideas

Check you remote server iptables configuration

`ìptables -L -n`

If you want to access Jboss directly, make sure you started it listening on all IP addresses of the machine e.g. pass the `-b 0.0.0.0` parameter

mySQL seems to only listen to requests made on the port 3306 of the 127.0.0.1 loopback, not on the external IP (chich makes sense AFAIC)

Glassfish seems configured to use IPV6